# How to extract the keys and values of an array without index

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I want to extract data from an array (original array with key and value). After I extract the array, I want two new arrays, the first one with just the keys, the second one with just the values, and both without indexes (see code example).

```
// original array 
$array = array(
    "name1"=>500
   ,"name2"=>400
   ,"name3"=>300
   ,"name4"=>200
   ,"name5"=>100
);

// after extraction
$array1 = array('name1','name2','name3','name4','name5');
$array2 = array(500,400,300,200,100);

// not like this
// $array1 = array(0=>'name1',1=>'name2',2=>'name3',3=>'name4',4=>'name5);
// $array2 = array(0=>500,1=>400,2=?300,3=>200,4=>100);
```

Comment: Every item in a PHP array *must* have an index. Your "not like this" arrays are exactly the same as the arrays you want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$array1 = array_keys($array);
$array2 = array_values($array);
```

well, you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure).

> In computer science, an array data structure or simply **an array is a
>   data structure consisting of a collection of elements (values or
>   variables), each identified by at least one array index or key**. An
>   array is stored so that the position of each element can be computed
>   from its index tuple by a mathematical formula.

Comment: _Please note_ that this is for people deling with HTTP requests and JSON values. I **succeeded** in getting an array without the indexes by creating an array and adding the desired elements one by one. The `print_r` function still shows the indexes, but when I returned the created array in a HTTP response, my frontend got just values (ex. `['a', 'b', 'c']`). [**Live demo here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b6e8da771e41508824c0668c13d5fff213f9e7c). The problem I had was that `array_filter` was returning the indexes (in JSON something like `{'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c'}`.

Comment: that what print_r function does [If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). maybe your frontend 'automatically' recognize it as an array because of the json format.

Comment: While I know that print_r does that, I had the same problem as the OP and I solved it by inserting the values into the array one by one (in a loop). JSON was showing `{0: 'a', 1: 'b'}` before the fix, and after I used the loop it was `['a','b']`.

Answer (score 10):

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
```

Note however that `array(0=>'item')` and `array('item')` are *exactly identical* as far as PHP is concerned. There is no such thing as a php array item without an index.  If you do not supply an index PHP will silently add a numeric index.