# "Collapse" associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This might have been answered, but I couldn't find a related question so here goes.

I have a simple associative array like so:

`$arr = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", ...)`

I want to "collapse" this associative array so that it becomes:

`$arr = array("value1", "value2", ...);`

So basically just throw away the keys.

I know how to do this with a loop, but does PHP have a built in function to do this?

Comment: user array_values function

Comment: @ChetanAmeta That's just it! If you want to make an answer out of that, I will mark it accepted.

Comment: PHP does have a builtin function to throw the keys and keep only the values. It is named [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: no need to answer it just simple :)

Comment: By the way [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870659/php-how-to-extract-the-array-of-keys-and-values-without-index), i think, was the question you were looking for.

Comment: @Y.Hermes Thanks. I'll flag this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). This will return all the values of an array

Let see example:

```
$arr = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");

print('<pre>');
print_r($arr);
print('</pre>');
//Output...
/*Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)*/


print('<pre>');
print_r(array_values($arr));
print('</pre>');

//Output...
/*Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
)*/
```